# Using multiple if statemens in foreach loop

Tags: powershell, csv, if-statement, foreach

In this script, I am trying to make a group (if not exist) and add users thats are not already in the group.

But the problem is he only takes the first if statement I think, because it don't seems like he is taking the next statements in the loop.

```
#Tweede test met if
$teams = #Here comes the csv file.
Foreach($team in $teams)
{
$Test = (Get-UnifiedGroup $team.DisplayName)
    if  (Get-UnifiedGroup $team.DisplayName)
    {
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "$($team.Displayname) already exists!"
     }
     elseif ($Test -eq "false")
     {
        $Group = New-UnifiedGroup -DisplayName $team.DisplayName -Alias $team.Alias -AccessType $team.AccessType
        }
   foreach($Member in $Members)
        {
    
   elseif (get-UnifiedgroepLinks $team.Links)
    {
        write-host -ForegroundColor Green "$($team.Links) already exists!"
    }
        else
    {
        Add-UnifiedGroupLinks -Identity $team.Identity -LinkType $team.Linktype -Links $team.Links
    }
}}
```

OK so this is my current output form @Theo last improvement

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHXmE.png)

OK I have something very interesting, because when I looked at the output of

`$existingMembers = @((Get-UnifiedGroupLinks -Identity $Group.DistinguishedName -LinkType Members).PrimarySMTPAddress)`

I will get certain blank spots. And when I ran the script for one user it was working but for another one it did not, so I looked at the user that did not worked, and he does not have a license. So I tested it further. And in my conclusion now it's working. So when an acc is unlicensed, it is not seen like he is added to that specific group. So he is also throwing the second if statement, but also the second else statement.

Does this make sense to you @Theo?

```
### script name: Users_Verwijderen                                                                                                                                      ###
### Datum updated: 14-12-2022                                                                                                                                           ###
### Auteur: Wessel Rouw                                                                                                                                                 ###
### Purpose script is to add groups and users in to groups in Azure.    ###
#######################################################################

$teams = import-csv #Here your CSV
foreach($team in $teams) {
$team | Format-Table
$Check = (Get-UnifiedgroupLinks -Identity $team.Identity -LinkType $team.Linktype)
$existingMembers = @((Get-UnifiedGroupLinks -Identity $Group.DistinguishedName -LinkType Members).PrimarySMTPAddress)
    $Group = (Get-UnifiedGroup $team.DisplayName)
    if  ($Group) 
    {
        Write-Host "$($team.Displayname) already exists!" -ForegroundColor Green
    }
    else 
    {
        Write-Host "Creating group $($team.Displayname)"
        $Group = New-UnifiedGroup -DisplayName $team.DisplayName -Alias $team.Alias -AccessType $team.AccessType
    }
    if ($existingMembers -contains $team.Links)
         {
        Write-Host "$($team.Links) already exists!" -ForegroundColor Green
         }
    else 
     {
        Write-Host "Creating group Links $($team.Links)"
        Add-UnifiedGroupLinks -Identity $team.Identity -LinkType $team.Linktype -Links $team.Links
     }
}
```

This is now my current script working with help from @Theo (Only, users that are not licensed will get the message that they are added even if they are already in the group).

Here is my input now in my csv.
I have changed username (Links) and the domain name (After the Test101 and the users (Links).

```
DisplayName,Alias,AccessType,Identity,Linktype,Links
Test101,Test101,private,Test101@domain.nl,Member,Hek_Sme@Domain.nl
Test101,Test101,private,Test101@domain.nl,Member,Mek_Lei@Domain.nl
Test101,Test101,private,Test101@domain.nl,Member,Wek_Bog@Domain.nl
```

This is another very helpful output. again same story as above with the changed domain and usernames.

```
Name                                         DisplayName GroupType PrimarySmtpA
                                                                   ddress      
----                                         ----------- --------- ------------
Test101_(**Here comes a private number)** Test101     Universal Test101@1...



PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $existingMembers
**Here comes the domain admin**
Hek_Sme@Domain.nl
Gek_Wel@Domain.nl
Gek_Wel@Domain.nl
Dir_Bog@Domain.nl

Wek_Bog@Domain.nl

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $inputMembers
Mek_Lei@Domain.nl

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

And as you can see some fields are empty and that are exactly the two users who don't own a licence and when I then run the command to get everyone who is not presenting in the get commando of users for that group it is specified to that users again.

I only don't know why this and if my thought is right?

Comment: For debugging add into the foreach loop : $team | Format-Table which will indicate all the properties.  You can also do for $Member : $Member | Format-Table.

Comment: No, you have the order of things wrong now. The lines to get the members in the links should go just above the second `if`. Then, `$team.Links` needs to be split on the comma giving you an array and then..  you cannot use `-contains` to see if an array is found in another array. It seems your problem is all in the input file where you have blank values in the Link field. See my final edit

Comment: Please show some more of your (sanitized) CSV file. So far, you show only the headers, but it is uncertain if the file is *comma** delimited or perhaps **semi-colon** (`;`) delimited, since you seem to live in Holland as I do too. What info is in the `Links` field in your csv? The user Names, EmailAddresses (would be perfect), SamAccountName or??? A csv file is just text, so you can open it in Notepad, copy the first 3 or 4 lines and paste that in your question as [formatted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) text. Just change real usernames etc. to fake ones.

Comment: @Theo sorry for the late reaction. I have added it to the first post. Yes, I am also from Holland.

Comment: ```Test101 already exists!
All members from the csv already existed in group Test101
Test101 already exists!
Adding members to group Test101
Test101 already exists!
All members from the csv already existed in group Test101```


This is now my current ouput, at one specific users it keeps saying thats he is adding the user. But that user is already in the team.

Comment: @Theo is it a possibility, that in this script he can't see an unlicensed user to be existing in a group, because for two users that are licensed it is working, but for the one that is not, he keeps saying that he is being added?

Comment: @Theo I have again updated my first post, so now you can see what my thoughts are with the current output.

Answer (score 0):

Oke, so thanks already for the help. Now it works better. But in the second part I want to verify that if a user already exists in azure it displays the message, but if don't it has to be added? But this is now the problem.

**This is now the output of my running script**
VERBOSE: Returning precomputed version info: 3.0.0
VERBOSE: POST with -1-byte payload
VERBOSE: received 2945-byte response of content type application/json;charset=utf-8
VERBOSE: Returning precomputed version info: 3.0.0
VERBOSE: POST with -1-byte payload
VERBOSE: received 2906-byte response of content type application/json;charset=utf-8
Test105 already exists!
Creating group Links #Here stand the email (Links)
VERBOSE: Returning precomputed version info: 3.0.0
VERBOSE: POST with -1-byte payload
VERBOSE: received 386-byte response of content type application/json;charset=utf-8

The problem is when a user already exist it does not goes to the line that says that it already exits but instead it skips this part i think and goed directy to the else statement.

I think I am pretty close now.

`$teams = import-csv #CSV here
{
#$team | Format-Table #This was voor debugging
$Check = (Get-UnifiedgroupLinks -Identity $team.Identity -LinkType $team.Linktype)

```
$Group = (Get-UnifiedGroup $team.DisplayName)
if  ($Group) 
{
    Write-Host "$($team.Displayname) already exists!" -ForegroundColor Green
}
else 
{
    Write-Host "Creating group $($team.Displayname)"
    $Group = New-UnifiedGroup -DisplayName $team.DisplayName -Alias $team.Alias -AccessType $team.AccessType
}
 if ($Check -contains $team.Links)
     {
    Write-Host "$($team.Links) already exists!" -ForegroundColor Green
     }
 else 
 {
    Write-Host "Creating group Links $($team.Links)"
    Add-UnifiedGroupLinks -Identity $team.Identity -LinkType $team.Linktype -Links $team.Links
 }
```

}`

[These are the columns of my csv.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qtmH.png)